# Ruby on Rails (SIGNIN and SIGNUP)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Ruby on rails** **login and signup form**

```
    Hi everyone i am new for ruby on rails , i am working a task of 
    registration and login page , i surfed through internet i'm not getting a 
    correct sample code for that any one please explain me...
```

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/devise-authentication-in-depth/

Answer (score 0):

Use [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem for authentication, and it's pretty simple to use just follow the steps in documentation.and even if you find any difficulty just follow the step

for more clear documentation follow the [get starter devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started)

Answer (score -1):

Imitating the complete code, blocks your brain from learning more.

Use [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem for authentication, and it's pretty simple to use just follow the steps in documentation.